# How to wait for an API response for maximum 15 seconds in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an API which sometimes does not return a response because of some dependencies. I need to wait for maximum 15 seconds for the response, if I don't receive any response within 15 seconds, I want to skip it and make the control goes to next line to execute next set of instructions.
This is how I have the API call:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await getData() // I want to await max 15 seconds here, if not next line should be executed 
  
  const response2 = await getSecondData()
}
```

How can I implement the same in react ?

Comment: Race it against a promise that resolves in 15 seconds? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

Comment: Thanks man, good input

Comment: Why delete good thoughts, i think your approach is really good @steve K

Answer (score 1):

`@steve K` deleted this answer, but i think its really cool answer, i prefer to repost it for literature purposes, because its a really great answer

```
const promiseTimeout = new Promise((resolve) => (setTimeout(() => resolve(false),  15000)))

const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await Promise.race([promiseTimeout, getData()]) // I want to await max 15 seconds here, if not next line should be executed 
  
  // You can do a check here if you need to
  if(!response) // do something 

  const response2 = await getSecondData()
}
```

Comment: Sorry didnt mean to delete it I must have done it on accident I need to fix my mouse it is doing weird ghost clicks but you can leave this one up. :)

Comment: Thanks mate, i always visit these good codes from time to time to be good at writing them on my own projects

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `getData` in a function that has the `timeout` set, and if it doesn't resolve within than time, than throw error.

```
function timeoutPromise(fn, timeout) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // reject if timeout happens
    setTimeout(() => { 
         reject('API_TIMEOUT');
    }, timeout);
    // handle the promise appropriately 
    fn().then((data) => resolve(data)).catch((err) => reject(err));
 })
}
```

Inside your code, you can do the following:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
     const response = await timeoutPromise(getData, 15000) // I want to await max 15 seconds here, if not next line should be executed 
  } catch(e) {
    // handle error
  }
  const response2 = await getSecondData()
}
```

This will work for Promises in general, but won't do things like `cancel` API call, meaning, if API times out, the server call won't be cancelled from browser.

Comment: well thats really an issue, cancelling API call... any input on that mate?

Comment: @ndotie what do you mean by "really an  issue"? The promise will be rejected and the code execution will continue as usual, with an exception that if the API call succeeds post timeout, it'll simply be discarded. 
By canceling I mean, browser will not close the fetch stream even if we reject the wrapper promise.

Comment: I got you now, we can always ignore the api call results

Answer (score 0):

waiting for 15 seconds then execute another function is not a react feature but just pure javascript.

```
const timer15sec = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 1500, 'overtime');
});
const firstCall =  getData();

Promise.race([timer15sec , firstCall ]).then(async (value) => {
  let response;
  if(value === 'overtime') { //means timer exceeded 15secs
      response = await getSecondData()
  }else { //not exceeded 15secs
      response = value
  }
 return  response
}).then(result => {
   //you can have your result here!!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch API

```js
const TIMEOUT = 15000; // Set timeout to 15 seconds

function fetchAPI(url, options) {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const { signal } = controller;

  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    controller.abort();
  }, TIMEOUT);

  return fetch(yourBaseURL, { ...options, signal })
    .then((response) => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      throw error;
    });
}

//Usage
fetchAPI('yourBaseURL', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  // handle the response
})
.catch((error) => {
  // handle the error
});
```

Axios

```js
//Base API
this.httpService = axios.create({
    baseURL: `yourBaseURL`,
    headers: headers,
    timeout: 15000, // 15 seconds
    timeoutErrorMessage: "Request timed out. Please try again later.",
});

//standalone
axios.get('yourBaseURL', { timeout: 15000 })
```